# Is my understanding of projectivism correct?

Tags: ethics, metaethics, emotivism

From Miller's *An Introduction to Contemporary Meta-ethics*:

> "Emotivism is a form of projectivism: when we use 'is wrong' in an evaluative judgement [...] we are treating 'wrong' as if it is a predicate akin to the nonevaluative predicates of our language [...] However, according to emotivism [...] this is inaccurate: and what we are doing when we treat wrongness as a genuine feature of things is *projecting* our sentiments or emotions onto the world. Wrongness is not really a property of things in the world: rather it is something we *project* onto the world when we form an attitude or sentiment towards it."

From [Standford's Encyclopedia of Philosophy](https://plato.stanford.edu/Archives/Fall2012/entries/moral-anti-realism/projectivism-quasi-realism.html):

> Projectivism is best thought of as a causal account of moral experience. Consider a straightforward, observation-based moral judgment: Jane sees two youths hurting a cat and thinks “That is impermissible.” [...] she judges the world to contain a certain quality, and her doing so is not the product of her tracking a real feature of the world, but is, rather, prompted by an emotional experience.

From these readings, my understanding of projectivism is as follows:

> (P) **Emotional experiences -as opposed to awareness of moral facts- are the *cause* of people treating evaluative judgements (e.g. "murder is wrong") as predicates (truth-apt).**

(P) does not seem to logically imply the non-existence of moral facts, but merely states that -whether they exist or not- they are not the cause of our evaluative judgements; projectivism leaving the door (arguably) open to moral facts is in accordance with the Standford  article.

---

**Is (P) a correct understanding of projectivism?**

Comment: Two corrections. First, projectivism does not have to be emotive, one can believe that people project something other than emotions onto the world, instincts or biases, for example. Second, while (P) does not imply non-existence of moral facts, it strongly suggests their irrelevance to our moral discourse, and hence their elimination on parsimony grounds. That is the driving force for adoption of emotivism, e.g. by positivists. [Moral sentimentalism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/moral-sentimentalism/), on the other hand, is more open to moral facts somehow prompting emotions.